# MongoDB 2d compound index scanning many more documents than returned

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, query-optimization

I have data in the following format:

```
{_id: ObjectId('...'), pos: [100, 100], uid: null}
{_id: ObjectId('...'), pos: [150, -100], uid: null}
{_id: ObjectId('...'), pos: [500, 137], uid: ObjectId('5b38d9876c08726511739141')}
{_id: ObjectId('...'), pos: [-980, 540], uid: uid: ObjectId('5b38d9876c08726511739141')}
...
```

I've created the following index:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "pos" : "2d",
        "uid" : 1
    },
    "name" : "pos_2d_uid_1",
    "ns" : "coll.entities",
    "min" : -104857600,
    "max" : 104857600
}
```

I then run the following query through `explain`:

```
db.coll.find({pos: {$geoWithin: {$box: [[-6949, 4064], [6408, -6468]]}}, uid: null});
```

And get the following results:

```
nReturned: 30
totalKeysExamined: 87753
totalDocsExamined: 87743
```

The collection has around 500k documents in it, so it isn't scanning the full collection (and it is using "FETCH" stage and the correct index). These queries are quite slow due to scanning so many documents, but since it is correctly matching the index, why would it be scanning so many documents rather than only scanning the number that are matched?

Comment: Could you post the whole explain result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is scrapping the geospatial query altogether and replacing it with two range queries like so:

```
db.coll.find({uid: null, 'pos.0': {$gte: -6949, $lte: 6408}, 'pos.1': {$gte: -6468, $lte: 4064}});
```

I then created the following index:

```
{uid: 1, 'pos.0': 1, 'pos.1': 1}
```

This change resulted in totalDocsExamined matching nReturned, which massively lowered the load on our MongoDB server.